# Django - Apache : How to change static repertory for upload files

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu, vps

I installed Django on a VPS and Apache2,
but when I want to upload a file (Avatar with userena)
I have this error `Permissions refused: 'var/www/static'`
but my css files and others have Loaded (file in the static directory of my project),
And the directory of my django project is in `/home/user/...` and not in `/var/www`, I tried a "DocumentRoot" change in `etc/apache2/site-available/000-Default.conf..'But it does not work
My conf in 000-default.conf :
```

        ServerName www.site_example.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@site_example

```
    DocumentRoot home/ubuntu/my_site/site_example/
    Alias /static /home/ubuntu/my_site/site_example/static
    <Directory /home/ubuntu/my_site/site_example/static >
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/home/ubuntu/my_site/site_example">
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess site_example python-path=/home/ubuntu/my_site/site_example python-home=/home/ubuntu/web_sites/my_site__venv
    WSGIProcessGroup site_example
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/my_site/site_example/wsgi.py
```

```

Comment: Your settings.py file (esp. MEDIA_ROOT) and the permissions on this path would be helpful, otherwise one can only guess.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to use this !!